# Bluetooth Adapter Dongle

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have a K380 Logitech Bluetooth keyboard that is not compatible with the Logitech Unifying Receiver. I have the receiver for my Logitech keyboard and mouse. I want to switch the keyboard to a Logitech K380 Bluetooth Keyboard.  My computer is an ASUS PC, Windows 10 64-bit, Processor IntelR Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20 GHz

Will a Avantree DG40S USB Dongle work with the k380 keyboard?
Will the Avantree Dongle interfere with the Unifying Receiver or visa versa?

Info on the Avantree Dongle:
https://www.amazon.ca/Avantree-Bluetooth-Computer-Keyboard-Warranty/dp/B00VWEK4IG?SubscriptionId=AKIAITNV2DFZ5GUWNVXQ&tag=gameslikeca-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00VWEK4IG

Info on the k380 keyboard:
[https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-K380-Multi-Device-Bluetooth-Keyboard/dp/B0148NPH9I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0148NPH9I)

Comment: In theory, they could interfere with each other because they’re both working in the 2.4 GHz band.

Answer (score -1):

Any Bluetooth device will work with any Bluetooth receiver, which in your case is the dongle.  So you are fine to use your K380 with that receiver.

There are a few caveats, when it comes to Bluetooth versions.  Some advanced features of a device while require a higher version.  However, many of these features are device specific, as in audio for example.  I have never seen a keyboard require Bluetooth v4 for any feature to work.

Comment: Thanks...Since the K380 keyboard is not compatible with the Logitech Unifying Receiver, I put in a Avantree Bluetooth adapter dongle. Tried to add the Bluetooth K380 keyboard but it won't add. My Bluetooth is all up to date.